# Need an example of using TypeWatch

Tags: jquery, ajax, typewatch

The TypeWatch jQuery plug-in was recommended in several older posts, but I'm having trouble using it (version 2.0).  I think the problem is my understanding of what's available to the callback when TypeWatch calls it and how to obtain data for the selected form element.

All of the examples I've been able to find in the past few hours use a simple alert() as the callback function, but what I need are the selected form input tag's value, alt tag, and title tag.  Would someone please explain to me or provide an example of how this is supposed to work?  Maybe if I knew what the this object is, I could answer my own questions.

I have a jQuery keyup handler working with AJAX - what I want to do now is incorporate the TypeWatch functionality to prevent server calls with each keystroke.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input#aspectSearch').typeWatch({
  callback:function(){
    $('.waiting-search').show();
    $('.search-result').remove();
    ajax_call_function();
    $('#filters-form #search_string').val(null);
  },
  wait:750,
  highlight:false,
  captureLength:2
});
```